# Python - Adding grouped mode as additional column in original dataset

Tags: python, pandas, mode, group

So I have data similar to this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Order ID':[555,556,557,558,559,560,561,562,563,564,565,566],
                   'State':["MA","MA","MA","MA","MA","MA","CT","CT","CT","CT","CT","CT"],
                   'County':["Essex","Essex","Essex","Worcester","Worcester","Worcester","Bristol","Bristol","Bristol","Hartford","Hartford","Hartford"],
                   'AP':[50,50,75,100,100,125,150,150,175,200,200,225]})
```

but I need to add a column that shows the mode of AP grouped by State and County. I can get the mode this way:

```
(df.groupby(['State', 'County']).AP.agg(Mode = (lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])).reset_index().round(0))
```

I'm just not sure how I can get that data added to the original data so that it looks like this:

| Order ID | State | County | AP | Mode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 555 | MA | Essex | 50 | 50 |
| 556 | MA | Essex | 50 | 50 |
| 557 | MA | Essex | 75 | 50 |
| 558 | MA | Worcester | 100 | 100 |
| 559 | MA | Worcester | 100 | 100 |
| 560 | MA | Worcester | 125 | 100 |
| 561 | CT | Bristol | 150 | 150 |
| 562 | CT | Bristol | 150 | 150 |
| 563 | CT | Bristol | 175 | 150 |
| 564 | CT | Hartford | 200 | 200 |
| 565 | CT | Hartford | 200 | 200 |
| 566 | CT | Hartford | 225 | 200 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for new column:

```
df['Mode'] = (df.groupby(['State', 'County']).AP
                .transform(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]))
```

Or [`Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html):

```
df['Mode'] = df.groupby(['State', 'County']).AP.transform(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0])
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael! Seems like we've never been up at the same times, but I see your answers often and and am always hoping to bump into you some time :)

Comment: I can say for one... @jezrael is a GOAT and richardec you are coming up right behind him as one of the best I've see in a while. :)

Comment: @ScottBoston agree~

Comment: @richardec haven't seen a new user like you for a long time ~